# EJB 3 deployment in JBoss AS 7

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1, jboss7.x

I am trying to prototype a simple EAR with EJB 3 / Hibernate 4 deployed on JBoss AS 7.

I have very simple / dumb classes:

EJB Interface:

```
@Local
public interface PrototypeObjectEJB {
    @TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    void persist(PrototypeObject o);
}
```

EJB Bean:

```
@Stateless
public class PrototypeObjectEJBBean implements PrototypeObjectEJB
{
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PrototypeObjectEJBBean.class);

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public void persist(PrototypeObject o) {
        logger.debug("[persist] start");
        em.persist(o);

        logger.debug("[persist] ends");
    }
```

}

My EAR structure:

```
EAR
+ lib
+ META-INF
  |- application.xml
  |- jboss-app.xml
  |- MANIFEST.MF
+ EJB.jar
  |- com (java classess / packages)
  |- META-INF
  |  |- MANIFEST.MF
  |- log4j.properties
  |- persistence.xml
+ Web.war
```

I am deploying on JBoss-as-7.1.0-CR1b, and I am getting:

```
10:40:42,010 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeplo
ymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-1) JNDI bindings for session bean name
d PrototypeObjectEJBBean in deployment unit subdeployment "JBossPrototype-EJB-1.
0.jar" of deployment "JBossPrototype-EAR-1.0.ear" are as follows:

        java:global/JBossPrototype-EAR-1.0/JBossPrototype-EJB-1.0/PrototypeObjec
tEJBBean!com.mythum.billing.ejb.PrototypeObjectEJB
        java:app/JBossPrototype-EJB-1.0/PrototypeObjectEJBBean!com.mythum.billin
g.ejb.PrototypeObjectEJB
        java:module/PrototypeObjectEJBBean!com.mythum.billing.ejb.PrototypeObjec
tEJB
        java:global/JBossPrototype-EAR-1.0/JBossPrototype-EJB-1.0/PrototypeObjec
tEJBBean
        java:app/JBossPrototype-EJB-1.0/PrototypeObjectEJBBean
        java:module/PrototypeObjectEJBBean

10:40:42,149 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC0000
1: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."JBossPrototype-EAR-1.0.ear"
."JBossPrototype-EJB-1.0.jar".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in s
ervice jboss.deployment.subunit."JBossPrototype-EAR-1.0.ear"."JBossPrototype-EJB
-1.0.jar".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "JBossProtot
ype-EJB-1.0.jar" of deployment "JBossPrototype-EAR-1.0.ear"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(Deplo
ymentUnitPhaseService.java:121) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.CR1b.jar:7.1.0.CR1b]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(Se
rviceControllerImpl.java:1824) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceCont
rollerImpl.java:1759) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExec
utor.java:886) [:1.6.0_24]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:908) [:1.6.0_24]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_24]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBA
S011047: Component class com.mythum.billing.ejb.PrototypeObjectEJBBean for compo
nent PrototypeObjectEJBBean has errors:
JBAS011440: Can't find a deployment unit named null in subdeployment "JBossProto
type-EJB-1.0.jar" of deployment "JBossPrototype-EAR-1.0.ear"
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor$1.hand
le(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:155)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ClassDescriptionTraversal.run(ClassDescript
ionTraversal.java:54)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.proces
sClassConfigurations(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:148)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.deploy
(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:141)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(Deplo
ymentUnitPhaseService.java:115) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.CR1b.jar:7.1.0.CR1b]
        ... 5 more
```

What am I missing to set up EJB properly?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem with the above is that I put persistence.xml in my EJB jar, rather than the EAR's META-INF